# Windows Server 2012 - restrict domain admin

Tags: permissions, administrator, group-policy, windows-domain

My personal workstation got connected to company domain however I'm not really okay with domain administrators having admin access to my computer. Can I locally restrict domain administrators while still staying within domain?

Comment: If it's your personal computer you have a choice to have it not joined to the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Policies applied by a Domain will supersede policies and settings you've applied locally.

If you must be connected to the Domain you have to accept that the Domain admins will have control over your computer.

If you cannot accept them having control over your computer, then you should remove your computer from the Domain.

Comment: It's pretty terrible feeling after working exclusively with Linux machines for years. I never felt such loose of control before :/

Comment: My first question would be "why connect your personal computer to their domain?". If you are a contractor, they should have ways to for you to work without joining your computer to their domain. By accepting your computer into their domain also they opened their domain up to anything on your computer, which would make me shake their IT staff while asking them also "Why?"

Comment: Originally it  was necessary to export my personal SSL keys for IPSec VPN connection. But I also think it's required if I want to use virtualization hosts in network. I don't know details of configuration. Tbh I'm using windows only because environment requires me to do so and I don't have much experience with windows dominated environments.

Comment: One solution would be to use a VM of your own. Leave the host OS clear of their meddling, and run a VM which you then connect to their domain.